# Angular doesn't see changes in JSON file

Tags: angularjs, caching

So I have this code to access data from JSON file.

```
taskAppControllers.controller('MainMenuCtrl', ['$scope','$http',
 function($scope, $http){
  $http.get('data/main-menu.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.mainMenuOptions = data
  });
}]);
```

Everything is fine. But when I change JSON files,  everything stays as it was. If I rename JSON file and access it, it will show updated data, and if afterwards, I rename it back, it will display the output from JSON before it was edited. It probably saves data in browser memory or something similar. It's cache related issue. How do I fix/reset it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound like caching issue, try appending random parameter to the URL, to force fetching a fresh copy from the server:

```
$http.get('data/main-menu.json?' + Math.random())
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that this is actually an angular-specific issue.  Your browser would likely cache this.

If main-menu.json should be static, consider just doing ctrl+F5 instead of F5 during your debug sessions.  If it needs to be updated, you could either change your caching-related response headers to let the browser know that it should not cache, or you could add a "cache buster" to the request by adding a timestamp as a request parameter.  That's not the preferred way to handle it, though.

Comment: I agree it's cache issue and its browser related. (when I open same path in different browser its actually updated). So I was trying to find how to make Angular skip this issue, something like Alon Eitan suggested in answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming i understand you correctly, Angular will not dynamically update in the way you're expecting.  It will only update when you reload the page or if you code it to reload the data from the server I.e recall the $http service.

You'll probably want to poll the server to check if the data changes or use something like SignalR to "push" the new data to the browser.